# Unable to index one or more source files for symbols file (Build vNext TFS 2015)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Using on-premises TFS 2015 running the task "Index Sources & Publish Symbols" with the following settings

```
Path to publish symbols: \\myserver\symbols
Search pattern: **\bin\**\*.pdb
Path to symbols folder: <I left this empty>
```

I always get the following error message

> Unable to index one or more source files for symbols file ....pdb

I tried it with debug and release configuration. With and without code optimization. Nothing. I always get this error.

It is important to note, that the pdb files are getting generated on the share(thus I think all the symbol server settings are corrent) but unfortunately they have the hardcoded path to the source files within.

What do I have to do to get the files indexed?
What could be the reason why all files can not be indexed?
What are the prerequisites for indexing files?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to use the empty of `Path to publish symbols` which only index the source. Did you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I get the same error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share the entire logs and your build definition? The error message usually displays when the pdb file is copied from another location.

Comment: Patrick and Eddie, thanks! I don't know what was the case but after updating the on-premises TFS to RC2 it is now working. The only warnings I see now is "Unable to index one or more source files for symbols file 'C:\[...]\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.pdb'." But that is ok! :) Thanks again.

Comment: We have the same problem with TFS2015 We get a lot of those messages in the log, basically for all our pdbs. All our csproj files a configured so that they build to the same common folder, maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your symbol server settings well. Details you can refer this link: [How easy is to use a Symbol Server with Team Build vNext?](http://mattvsts.blogspot.jp/2015/07/how-easy-is-to-use-symbol-server-with.html)

Comment: The pdb files are getting generated on the share (thus I think all the symbol server settings are corrent) but unfortunately they have the hardcoded path to the source files within...